# Using over 2gb sd card space for link2sd apps

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, sd-card, link2sd, samsung-galaxy-s-3-mini

i have a rooted S3 mini, android version 4.1.2, link2sd free edition installed. S3 mini doesn't support moving apps to SD so I have to use Link2SD. I have 4 GB sd and I have followed the instructions [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHsHiXDgSy4) to partition it.

Today, I have bought a 64 GB SD card to replace the 4 GB sd card that I have. At about the second minute of the video, the guy says you can go as high as 2 GB for your apps.

My question is, can you go higher than that? can you link say 16 GB of apps to SD using link2SD? I have 64 GB  card so 2 GB is nothing, my internal memory is 8GB so I need that extra space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Im using 32gb card.
I have kept 4096mb as EXT4 partition and rest I have formatted as FAT32. Link2SD works fine.

You can go max 4GB.

1. Download mini partition tool
2. Format your CLASS10 SDCARD 1st partition being FAT32, and second keep (4GB) it EXT2 (EXT4 might not work)
3. Shutdown your phone, put back your card. Star the phone.
4. And then start linking your files with Link2SD. I have bought Plus version, it is very useful. Since My phone has only 16GB internal memory.

Comment: It might be helpful if you added a link to this "mini partition tool" you're recommending.

Comment: So I can't link more than 4 gb apps to my sd?

Comment: 4gb is for swap memory kinda ram.  Rest is your space for moving your apps.

Comment: @DanHulme here u go http://www.minitool.com/